# Merge 2 images together

Tags: php, image, merge, gd

So far the following code successfully merges 2 images together ($dest is 573x311 abd $src is 428x255). The merged result is 573x311. Here it is:

```
  $dest = imagecreatefrompng('images/project-laptop.png');
  $src = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/project-laptop-site.jpg');
  $merged_image = "images/project-laptop-site_merged.png";

  imagealphablending($dest, false);
  imagesavealpha($dest, true);

  imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 73, 19, 0, 0, 428, 255, 100);

  imagepng($dest, $merged_image);
```

Even though this works, **what I really want** is to reverse the order (put $dest on top of $src, ie the png on top the jpg and have the resulting size be 573x311). The following code hasn't worked:

```
  $src = imagecreatefrompng('images/project-laptop.png');
  $dest = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/project-laptop-site.jpg');
  $merged_image = "images/project-laptop-site_merged.png";

  imagealphablending($dest, false);
  imagesavealpha($dest, true);

  imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 73, 19, 0, 0, 573, 311, 100);

  imagepng($dest, $merged_image);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think copying a larger image into a smaller image is supported. Either crop the larger image to the size of the smaller image, then copy. Or, create a blank image of the larger size, then copy both over it.